# Pass the values from a dataset with indexes and values to a sparse Numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to make a sparse numpy array using the indexes and values stored in a pandas DataSet

The dataset has 'userIndex', 'movieIndex' and 'rating' with a million rows

For example:

| -- | movieIndex | userIndex | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 4 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 4.0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 4.0 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 3.0 |

Would be transformed to a numpy array like this:

[[0   0   0   0  2.5],
[0   4.0  0   0   0],
[4.0  0  3.0  0   0],
[0    0   0   0   0],
[0    0  3.0  0   0]]

So, first I'm making a np.zeros array with the correct size:

```
Y = np.zeros([nm,nu])
```

And for now, I'm passing the information as:

```
for i in range(len(ratings)):
  Y[int(ratings.iloc[i].movieIndex),int(ratings.iloc[i].userIndex)]
    = ratings.iloc[i].rating
```

And it works just fine with O(n), so it's not really bad but it takes 3 minutes to do so.
I know it's not a good idea to use "for" in a dataset, and I should use the vector functions to do it, but I can't find a way to make this work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it will work faster:

```
Y[ratings["movieIndex"].values, ratings["userIndex"].values] = ratings["rating"].values
```